# Inject object into scope of transcluded content in Angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to create a directive that has transcluded content that the directive can bind to and modify.  The directive has an isolate scope.  I imagine it working something like this:

```
<my-directive bound-item-name="childObj">
  <input ng-model="childObj.someField">
</my-directive>
```

At runtime, I want to use `childObj` as an alias for an object on `my-directive`'s isolate scope called `activeObject`.  Essentially, you might think of this as similar to the way `ng-repeat` lets you use a statment like `obj as alias in objList` and in the transcluded content `alias` refers to the individual instance.

I can't seem to figure out how I can actually do this... if I change the transluded content to refer to `$parent.activeItem` it does work the way I intended, but I feel like that's expecting the transcluded content to know too much about how the directive works.  It seems like modifying in the compile function might work, except I can't see, in the docs, how I can actually do that with the transcluded content.  Forcing the transcluded content to share its scope with the directive would be OK, although I see no evidence that there's some way to do that.

This must be possible, but how?

Fiddling around with this some more, I am able to get it to work by modifying `scope.$$childHead[scope.boundItemName]` instead of using `scope.activeObject` in the directive.  While this works I'd like to not rely on undocumented internal objects, if possible.

Comment: just dont do isolated scope for directive

Comment: @PawełSmołka That's not an option in my case.  Or if it is I'd have to resolve a bunch of other problems it would cause.

Comment: so i think you need to place your code to fiddle and link it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link` function of the directive is given the `transclude` function as the 5th parameter.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
  // ...
}
```

This `transclude` function takes a scope variable that you can create and another function - called "clone linking function" - that places the pre-linked transcluded content in the DOM. The `transclude` function links against that scope variable that you provided.

Here's how it works.

```
transclude: true,
scope: {}, // you are free to use whatever scope you need
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){

  var boundObj = {}; // your object
  var alias = attrs.boundItemName;

  // let's create an isolate scope for the transcluded content
  var newScope = scope.$new(true); 
  newScope[alias] = boundObj;

  transclude(newScope, function(preLinkContent){

     element.append(preLinkContent);
  });
}
```

Then, if you used your example:

```
<my-directive bound-item-name="foo">
   <input ng-model="foo.text">
</my-directive>
```

Then, the transcluded `ng-model` would write into your internal `boundObj`'s `.text` property.

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KTXqzDtra6I20oqVlBvG?p=preview)**

Comment: Follow-up question so I can try this out... if I'm putting in a manual function like this, do I need to remove the ng-transclude directive?  I'm assuming I do and I just need to use the function passed to the transclude function to find the place in the template I want to inject the content.

Comment: Yeah, you need to remove the `ng-transclude` from the template.

Comment: @Casey, did my answer address your question?

Comment: I haven't had the opportunity to try your code.  Sorry... I haven't forgotten about this.

Comment: Is there a way to get the transclude function in an angularjs 1.5 component?